Django + Dask integration: usage and progress?
About performance & best practice

Note, the entire code for the question below is public on Github.
Feel free to check out the project! https://github.com/b-long/moose-dj-uv/pull/3

I'm trying to workout a simple Django + Dask integration, where one view starts a long-running process and another view is able to check the status of that work.  Later on, I might enhance this in a way that get_task_status (or some other Django view function) is able to return the output of the work.
I'm using time.sleep(2) to intentionally mimic a long-running bit of work.  Also, it's important to see the overall work status as "running".  To that end, I'm also using a time.sleep() in my test, which feels very silly.
Here's the view code:
from uuid import uuid4
from django.http import JsonResponse
from dask.distributed import Client
import time

# Initialize Dask client
client = Client(n_workers=8, threads_per_worker=2)

NUM_FAKE_TASKS = 25

# Dictionary to store futures with task_id as key
task_futures = {}


def long_running_process(work_list):
    def task_function(task):
        time.sleep(2)
        return task

    futures = [client.submit(task_function, task) for task in work_list]
    return futures


def start_task(request):
    work_list = []

    for t in range(NUM_FAKE_TASKS):
        task_id = str(uuid4())  # Generate a unique ID for the task
        work_list.append(
            {"address": f"foo--{t}@example.com", "message": f"Mail task: {task_id}"}
        )

    futures = long_running_process(work_list)
    dask_task_id = futures[0].key  # Use the key of the first future as the task ID

    # Store the futures in the dictionary with task_id as key
    task_futures[dask_task_id] = futures

    return JsonResponse({"task_id": dask_task_id})


def get_task_status(request, task_id):
    futures = task_futures.get(task_id)

    if futures:
        if not all(future.done() for future in futures):
            progress = 0
            return JsonResponse({"status": "running", "progress": progress})
        else:
            results = client.gather(futures, asynchronous=False)

            # Calculate progress, based on futures that are 'done'
            progress = int((sum(future.done() for future in futures) / len(futures)) * 100)

            return JsonResponse(
                {
                    "task_id": task_id,
                    "status": "completed",
                    "progress": progress,
                    "results": results,
                }
            )
    else:
        return JsonResponse({"status": "error", "message": "Task not found"})


I've written a test, which completes in about 5.5 seconds:
from django.test import Client
from django.urls import reverse
import time


def test_immediate_response_with_dask():
    client = Client()
    response = client.post(reverse("start_task_dask"), data={"data": "foo"})
    assert response.status_code == 200
    assert "task_id" in response.json()

    task_id = response.json()["task_id"]
    response2 = client.get(reverse("get_task_status_dask", kwargs={"task_id": task_id}))
    assert response2.status_code == 200
    r2_status = response2.json()["status"]
    assert r2_status == "running"

    attempts = 0
    max_attempts = 8

    while attempts < max_attempts:
        time.sleep(1)
        try:
            response3 = client.get(
                reverse("get_task_status_dask", kwargs={"task_id": task_id})
            )
            assert response3.status_code == 200

            r3_status = response3.json()["status"]
            r3_progress = response3.json()["progress"]

            assert r3_progress >= 99
            assert r3_status == "completed"
            break  # Exit the loop if successful
        except Exception:
            attempts += 1
            if attempts == max_attempts:
                raise  # Raise the last exception if all attempts failed


My question is, is there a more performant way to implement this same API?  What if NUM_FAKE_TASKS = 10000?
Am I wasting cycles?
Edit: How to view progress percentage?
Thanks to @GuillaumeEB for the tip.
So, we know that the following is blocking:
client.gather(futures, asynchronous=False)

But, it seems like this also doesn't behave the way expect:
client.gather(futures, asynchronous=True)

Is there some way that I could use client.persist() or client.compute(), to see incremental progress?
I know that I can't persist a list of <class 'distributed.client.Future'> , and using client.compute(futures) also seems to behave incorrectly (jumping the progress from 0 to 100).

results = client.gather(futures, asynchronous=False) : this will block until futures are done, so this will not return until your task is done. Considering your answer, other than that this should work well, and easily handle 10000 tasks.

Thank you, @GuillaumeEB . That explains why my progress jumps from 0 to 100% :) I've edited my question to expand on the behavior I'm seeing, and my goal.

What's the point of making your function async when you're going to do everything synchronously anyways?

Good question @AbdulAzizBarkat , the async is not necessary.  It was a rushed copy & paste.  I'll remove it.

I think the solution you are looking for is as_completed:
https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/futures.html#waiting-on-futures.

You can also iterate over the futures as they complete using the as_completed function


Thank you, @GuillaumeEB , I've tried implementing this in a variety of ways, but I just can't get it right.  I end up with an exception from Django: django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet.  I've tried  creating a NannyPlugin and WorkerPlugin to solve that, but I'm failing.  Is there any chance you could provide more detail and maybe a working Django example?   I'd be happy to award the 100 point bounty if so.  Thanks again!

thanks again for your answer.  I'm not sure why, my own answer was downvoted & deleted.  Repeating the info here: "I've found the following project provides a great recipe for Dask + Django integration: https://github.com/MoonVision/django-dask-demo"
